# Автозапуск root

Tags: debian

Вообщем есть куча с серверов, ssh, бывает что ребутнется и нужно поднять одну программу. Программа(c++), экскютит команду, парсит результат и по полученному результату экскютит еще одну команду(ее можно исполнить только под рутом), хотелось бы просто в if-up.d вдолбить команду аля "screen -d -m /home/user/program" без ввода лишних паролей, много серверов, штук 30-40...

Comment: почитайте как пишутся инит скрипты, /etc/init.d/ если не осилите, то /etc/rc.local

Comment: Как-то совсем туманно.Вы хотите чтобы при загрузке выполнялась последовательность команд? Или проблема в том, что много серверов и вам лень на каждый из них закинуть init-скрипт?

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов много - один предложили выше. С if-up.d вариант сразу же не откидывайте - возможно, достаточно [настроить sudo](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=sudoers&category=5&russian=0) на выполнение нужной команды/скрипта без пароля?

Answer (score 0):

Если работать ручками - то можно порекомендовать [ClusterSSH - инструмент сетевого администрирования](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/l-ClusterSSH/index.html). Сам пока не юзал, но описание обнадеживающее (как и источник):

> ClusterSSH— это утилита для одновременного выполнения команд и внесения изменений в файлы конфигурации на нескольких хостах (серверах) сети, которая может быть полезной не только сетевым администраторам, но и опытным пользователям, управляющим собственной локальной сетью.

Comment: Да управления это одно, просто бывает по каким то причинам сервер отвалился, его подняли, и приходится входить из под рута чтобы поднять одну долбанную софтинку

Comment: удаленно же? ну и таким же макаром - какая разница...